# How to pass Querystring from source code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass querystring from html source code, the link is within the ItemTemplate of a ListView

```
<a href='<%# "Photos.aspx?AlbumID="+Eval("AlbumID") "&address=" + Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() %>'>
```

i tried this code but it did not work. There are multiple errors.

Comment: How did it not work? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: @Matt CS1026: ) expected

Comment: @Arbaaz Please mark the best answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be just `Request["Id"]`.

However, that returns an object of type `object` and when used with `+` operator with a string, does not need the `ToString()` method being called on it. It is called automatically during concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a + after your Eval() and a runat="server" on the a tag. Also, I prefer asp:HyperLink instead of a normal a tag for databound stuff:

```
<asp:Listview runat="server" ID="TestLV">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="TestHL" NavigateUrl='<%# "Photos.aspx?AlbumID=" + Eval("AlbumID") + "&address=" + Request.QueryString["Id"] %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Listview>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have error with Concatenating the valus ...Can you try like below...

May be it will help you...

```
 <a href='Photos.aspx?AlbumID=<%# Eval("AlbumID") + "&address=" + Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() %>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two errors. One is that you're forgetting one + operand after Eval, and the other is that the eval returns an object and putting this type of inline code does not call the method ToString() automatically, so you must set it explicitly: Eval("AlbumID").ToString().

Hope this helps.

```
<a href='<%# "Photos.aspx?AlbumID="+ Eval("AlbumID").ToString() + "&address=" + Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() %>'>
```